# Wix conditionals and preprocessor variables

Tags: wix

I want to change the value of a Wix variable depending on whether a value is defined or otherwise. In my wixproj I have:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'TFS Live|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <WixVariables>LIVE</WixVariables>
    <DefineConstants>LIVE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

...and in my wxs I have:

```
<?ifdef LIVE ?>
<?define binaryPath = "C:\Builds\5\IT Aerodynamics\RBT.TestSpec.LiveRelease\Binaries" ?>
<?else?>
<?define binaryPath = "C:\Builds\5\IT Aerodynamics\RBT.TestSpec.CI\Binaries" ?>
<?endif?>
```

...but when I build the appropriate configuration, the ifdef never fires. I always get the second value for `binaryPath`. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

That code works for me. One thing to check is that you don't have another `DefineConstants` MSBuild Property later in the .wixproj that doesn't look like:

```
<DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);OtherVars=Value</DefineConstants>
```

The default .wixproj template creates projects where the `Debug` preprocessor variable is defined like:

```
<DefineConstants>Debug</DefineConstants>
```

And that will overwrite `DefineConstants` defined higher in the project for debug builds. Otherwise, everything looks fine.

Comment: Never thought to check for this. You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 2):

One more thing, in addition to the @RobMensching answer.

If you build your solution using command line and msbuild, and if you define your DefineConstants in that build command, all your defines in projects will be overridden with those defined in command line:

```
msbuild Your.sln /t:Build
        /p:Configuration=TFSLive
        /p:Platform=x86
        /p:DefineConstants=Your;Defines;Here
```